# Как убрать текст, но оставить тег img? (библиотека simple-html-dom)

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
$html = file_get_html("http://pefilme.com"); //работает и с https://

foreach($html->find('div.post') as $element) {
        $img1   = strip_tags($element,"<img>");
        $img   = $img1->innertext;



        print($img);
}
```

Что тут не так?

Почему не убирает текст?

Comment: Текст так не убрать. Эта функция пытается возвратить строку, из которой удалены все NULL-байты, HTML- и PHP-теги: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: А не легче воспользоваться phpQuery ? - много ума не надо, чтобы понять как работает и видосы в ютубе есть... и он проще для понимания, чем simple-html-dom